# Interface Método GET e POST com Angular + Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Estou com algumas dúvidas de iniciante e queria a ajudar de vocês.
Criei uma Automação Residencial, baseada em Microcontrolador + Node.js + Angular.js.

A comunicação do Angular.js com o Microcontrolador está OK.
Porém, também farei o inverso. No qual o MIC irá enviar um comando POST para o Node.js, mais ou menos com esse parametro:

```
router.post('/Saidas', function(req,res) {
    saida = req.body.atuador;
    estado = req.body.estado;
    final = saida + estado;
    res.send('Enviado = Saida: ' + saida + '; Estado: ' + estado);
});
```

E posteriormente irei enviar para o site em HTML, via Angular.js com esse comando:

```
router.get('/SaidasSite', function(req,res){
    res.send(final);
});
```

**Acima está no código caminhos.js para o Node.js.

Porém, no meu Angular.js, fiz o seguinte código:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('Saidas',[]);
    app.controller('Status', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $interval(function(){
            var request = $http.get('/SaidasSite');    
            request.success(function(data) {
                if (data='QTD1LEDON') {
                    $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on');
                } else (data='QTDLEDOFF'){
                    $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('off');
                } else (data='QTD2LEDON'){
                    $('#QTD2LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on')
                } else { $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on'); }
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        }, 5000); 

        /* O segundo parâmetro "5000", diz que a função deve ser repetida a cada 
           5000 milisegundos (5 segundos) */
    });
</script>
```

A minha idéia é a seguinte: Quando eu enviar o comando "QTD1LEDON" para o comando POST /Saidas, ele enviar o comando para o Node.js e posteriomente o site irá receber o comando GET com esse valor (GET /SaidasSite) e acionar um botão conforme a string que recebeu.

Ex: Botão QTD1LED ON acionado -> QTDLEDON -> Ativa Botão "Bootstrap Toogle".

Não estou encontrando o melhor jeito para fazer isso. Esse processo não está funcionando. Nesse código, ele sempre aciona o "QTD1LEDON".

Teria algum jeito melhor para arrumar esse código ou implantar outro processo? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Fala Luiz, boa tarde.

No seu código em JavaScript, nos ifs, você deve utilizar o operador == ou o operador === para verificar se a constante é igual a variável (como é string sugiro o === pois é mais performático).

O operador = é operador de atribuição, então no primeiro if, ele atribui "QTD1LEDON" à variável data e como ela é uma variável definida ele entra no if. Por isso está entrando no primeiro if sempre.

Sugiro colocar também um console.log('data = ', data) no começo da function de callback de success para você poder ver o que veio de resposta do nodejs.

Outra coisa também é o else - quando você tem outra condição ele deve ser else if( condição ).

Espero ter ajudado.